# productsRequest not working in swift for In-App Purchases

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I wrote some code to get my In-app purchase to get rid on my ads. The response comes back blank, and comes back with error because it is nil here is my full code for In-App Purchase:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    outRemoveAds.enabled = false

    if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        println("IAP is enabled, loading")
        var productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects: "com.webstart.tomsgamesinc.StartLight_No_Ads")
        var request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        println("please enable IAPS")
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func buyProduct() {
    println("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
    var pay = SKPayment(product: p)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
}

//3
func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
    println("product request")
    println(response.products)
    var myProduct = response.products

    for product in myProduct {
        println("product added")
        println(product.productIdentifier)
        println(product.localizedTitle)
        println(product.localizedDescription)
        println(product.price)

        list.append(product as! SKProduct)
    }

    outRemoveAds.enabled = true
}

// 4
func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
    println("transactions restored")

    var purchasedItemIDS = []
    for transaction in queue.transactions {
        var t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction

        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

        switch prodID {
        case "com.webstart.tomsgamesinc.StartLight_No_Ads":
            println("remove ads")
            removeAds()
        default:
            println("IAP not setup")
        }

    }
}

// 5
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    println("add paymnet")

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        var trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
        println(trans.error)

        switch trans.transactionState {

        case .Purchased:
            println("buy, ok unlock iap here")
            println(p.productIdentifier)

            let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
            switch prodID {
            case "com.webstart.tomsgamesinc.StartLight_No_Ads":
                println("remove ads")
                removeAds()
                println("add coins to account")
            default:
                println("IAP not setup")
            }

            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        case .Failed:
            println("buy error")
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        default:
            println("default")
            break;

        }
    }
}

    // 6
    func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction)
    {
        println("finish trans")
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(trans)
    }

    //7
    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, removedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)
    {
        println("remove trans");
    }
 @IBAction func btnRemoveAds(sender: UIButton) {
    for product in list {
        println("ProdID")
        var prodID = product.productIdentifier
        println(prodID)
        if(prodID == "com.webstart.tomsgamesinc.StartLight_No_Ads") {
            p = product
            buyProduct()
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

I did add the purchase in iTunes connect.

Comment: Can you share your bundle id for app so I can test it at my side?

Comment: com.webstarts.tomsgamesinc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code like this:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    var productID = "com.webstart.tomsgamesinc.StartLight_No_Ads"
    var product: SKProduct?
    var isProductRecive = false
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getProductInfo()
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    }

    @IBAction func btnRemoveAds(sender: UIButton) {

        if isProductRecive{

            let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)

        }else{

            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Alert"
            alert.message = "Retriving product please wait."
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
            alert.show()
            getProductInfo()
        }
    }

    func getProductInfo()
    {
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: NSSet(objects: self.productID) as Set<NSObject>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Alert"
            alert.message = "Please enable In App Purchase in Settings."
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
            alert.show()
        }
    }

    //3
    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
        var products = response.products

        if (products.count != 0) {
            product = products[0] as? SKProduct
            self.isProductRecive = true
            println(product)
        } else {

            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Alert"
            alert.message = "Product not found"
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
            alert.show()
        }

        products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers

        for product in products
        {
            println("Product not found: \(product)")
        }
    }

    // 4
    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
        println("transactions restored")

        var purchasedItemIDS = []
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            var t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction

            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

            switch prodID {
            case "com.webstart.tomsgamesinc.StartLight_No_Ads":
                println("remove ads")
            default:
                println("IAP not setup")
            }

        }
    }

    // 5
    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
        for transaction in transactions as! [SKPaymentTransaction] {

            switch transaction.transactionState {

            case .Restored:

                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)

            case .Purchased:


                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)

            case .Failed:

                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)

            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    func request(request: SKRequest!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {

        println("There was an error");
    }
}
```

And it is working fine with my app bundle ID an product ID so kindly check into iTunes connect problem should be there.

Comment: is this working under Swift2? Because response variable becomes a String under Swift 2 and I dunno how to solve this. Do you have any idea?

Comment: honestly, this is a terrible answer.  Did you change anything?  Mention what you changed instead of including the whole block of code.  Hard to find the tweaks you made this way.

Comment: I did same, but when I tap cancel on Confirm purchase to use with Touch id transaction still goes through..

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for my game and returns back how many products there are to purchase. Works for xCode 7.1.1.

```
var products = [SKProduct]()
var product: SKProduct?

//StoreKit protocol method. Called when the AppStore responds
func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {

    var item = response.products

    if item.count != 0 {
        for var i = 0; i < item.count; i++ {
            product = item[i] as SKProduct
            products.append(product!)
        }
    }

    print("There are \(products.count) items to buy.")
}
```